# Android Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, color-coding

Can anyone tell me how to implement different colors for individual items of recyclerview? Actually, my recyclerview items are video items and they are assigned types also (classical, pop, etc), and I want to assign colors according to the type.

How do I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you set up all the views for a `RecyclerView` item in `onBindViewHolder()` function of the adapter.
So, have a `LinearLayout` (or other layout) for your item, find the layout in the `onBindViewHolder()` and use `setBackgroundColor()` on it.

Comment: OnBindView holder has the 'position' parameter so you can identify for which row and thus item for which its called